# SOHO router cannot establish connection from wired -> wireless until pinging from wireless -> wired

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, wired

I am currently setting up a SOHO network with mixed wired and wireless clients using a consumer-grade 100Mbit/802.11g router. I've found that wireless clients are "invisible" (pings never returned, nmap finds nothing) from wired clients, but as soon as I establish a connection from the wireless client to the wired one, the wireless client becomes visible. To be a little more succinct:

`[wired ~]$ ssh jill@wireless` (no host available)

`[wireless ~]$ ping wired` (success)

`[wired ~]$ ssh jill@wireless` (success?!)

I've tried multiple wireless clients (Windows and Linux based) and they all exhibit this issue. Does anyone recognize this issue? What could be the possible causes of this?

Comment: Are you using IPs or DNS/NetBIOS in your testing?

Comment: IP. Sorry to give a deceptive example.

Comment: What router is this? Sadly, many consumer grade routers (cheifly Netgear routers) use broken software bridging between their wireless and wired ports. There may be configuration options that will help. It could also be that the wireless clients are shutting off their interface when they're not using them to save power.

Comment: sounds like ARP suppression on the wireless router.  Is there any "isolation" or "wireless DMZ" feature enabled?

Comment: It is indeed a Netgear router... There is no mention of wireless DMZ or isolation in the manual or web interface. I have gone through the router settings quite thoroughly in attempt to sort this out. Currently it's a very simple setup with static IP assignments and no real distinction between wired and wireless clients that I can see. No suspicious messages in the log file either.

Comment: Also regarding the comment about wireless clients potentially shutting down their interface to save power: To test for this I set up two wired clients. I had to ping each wired client individually before that client could connect to the wireless one, which indicates it's not an energy saving routine.

Comment: As gravyface stated, this sounds like an ARP issue to me. Run a packet capture on the wired client and attempt an SSH connection to the wireless client and look at the ARP packets in the capture to see if that gives you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: I suspect if you change to a non-Netgear router, the problem will go away. Netgear has big problems with ARP and DHCP between wired and wireless clients. The software bridging is borked. I've shelved all my Netgear routers because of these issues. (See, for example, issue number 1 in [this Netgear support page](http://support.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/965).)